# Create a graph from a binary column in a dataframe - R

Tags: r

I need to create a point graph using the "ggplot" library based on a binary column of a dataframe.

```
df <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)
```

I need a point to be created every time the value "1" appears in the column, and all points are on the same graph. Thanks.

Comment: By "point graph" do you mean [scatter plot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html)?  If so, you need to provide another variable to define the second dimension.  If not, what is your expected output?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

y <- df
is.na(y) <- y == 0

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = seq_along(y), y), mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1), 
                     labels = c("0" = "0", "1" = "1"),
                     limits = c(0, 1))
```

It only plots points where `df == 1`, not the zeros. If you also want those, don't run the code line starting `is.na(y)`.

Comment: This was what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the binary column you talk about is associated to some other variables, then I think this might work:

(I've just created some random x and y which are the same length as the binary 0, 1s you provided)

```
x <- rnorm(22)
y <- x^2 + rnorm(22, sd = 0.3)
df <- data.frame("x" = x, "y" = y,
                 "binary" = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))

library(ggplot2)
# this is the plot with all the points
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
# this is the plot with only the points for which the "binary" variable is 1
ggplot(data = subset(df, binary == 1), mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
# this is the plot with all points where they are coloured by whether "binary" is 0 or 1
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, colour = as.factor(binary))) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but here are a few options. Since your data structure is not a data frame, I've renamed it `test`. First, dotplot with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(test), aes(x=test)) + geom_dotplot()
```

[image]

Or you could do the same thing as a bar:

```
qplot(test, geom="bar")
```

[image]

Or, a primitive base R quick look:

plot(test, pch=16, cex=3)

[image]